# Stream returns wrong type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to understand reactive style. But stuck on this example.

```
public class ScriptServiceImpl implements ScriptService{

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScriptServiceImpl.class);
    private final ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    private final ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

    @Override
    public Flux<MyFunctionResult> evaluate(MyFunction myFunction, Integer iterations){
        Flux<MyFunctionResult> flux = Flux.empty();
        flux.mergeWith(
                Flux.range(1,iterations)
                .map(counter -> {
                    engine.put("parametr", counter);
                    try {
                        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        String functionResult = engine.eval(myFunction.getSource()).toString();
                        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

                        return Mono.just(new MyFunctionResult(timer, functionResult, myFunction.getNumber(), counter));
                    } catch (ScriptException ex) {
                        return Mono.error(ex);
                    }
                })
        );
        return flux;
    }
}
```

I want to return `Flux` of `MyFunctionResult` but get `Flux` of `Object` in `Flux.mergeWith` section. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be that try/catch block is not allowed there?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues here

- you don't need to wrap `MyFunctionResult` into `Mono`. `map` expects none-reactive return type. As result, instead of `Mono.error` you should just wrap checked exception into unchecked `RuntimeException`.
- you need to return result of the `flux.mergeWith` and not `flux`. But in general for this example you don't need `mergeWith`

Your code could be converted into

```
return Flux.range(1,iterations)
        .map(counter -> {
            engine.put("parametr", counter);
            try {
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                String functionResult = engine.eval(myFunction.getSource()).toString();
                long timer = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

                return new MyFunctionResult(timer, functionResult, myFunction.getNumber(), counter);
            } catch (ScriptException ex) {
                throw Exceptions.propagate(ex);
            }
        });
```

In addition, not sure about `engine.eval` but in case this is blocking code consider wrapping it and run on a separate scheduler [How Do I Wrap a Synchronous, Blocking Call?](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking)